# How to add items to a list with multiple objects?

Tags: list, flutter, object, dart

I want to create a Weight Diary, where the user can add his weight with the day to a List. So I created a class and a List to save the weight with the day.

```
class WeightData {
  final DateTime date;
  final double weight;

  const WeightData({
    this.date,
    this.weight,
  });
}

List<WeightData> weights = [
  WeightData(date: DateTime.now(), weight: 56),
  WeightData(date: DateTime.now(), weight: 55.5),
];
```

My first question is, is that the right way to do this?

I also want that the user can dynamically add new weights, but I dont know how. My Code looks like this so far:

```
void newEntry() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      validator: (input) =>
                          input.trim().isEmpty ? 'Please enter Day' : null,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      validator: (input) =>
                      input.trim().isEmpty ? 'Please enter Weight' : null,
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          );
        });
  }
```

Because there are to entrys to make (day and weight) I dont know how to add this two objects (is this the right word?) to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `Column` add a `ElevatedButton` and check if `_formKey` is validated and then add to the list:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      weights.add(WeightData(date: DateTime.now(), weight: weightController.value),) 
    }
  },  
  child: Text('Submit'),
 ),
```

Get the value using `TextEditingController` inside the `TextFormField`:

```dart
TextEditingController weightController= TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  controller: weightController //here,
  validator: (input) =>
     input.trim().isEmpty ? 'Please enter Day' : null,
  ),
```

Comment: When i type in a weight and click on Submit nothing happen and when i hot reload i got a new List entry but there is 'null' instead of the write I typed in

Comment: Add a `print(weightController.value)` before the if case `if (_formKey.currentState!.validate())` to see if has a value

Comment: I got this output: TextEditingValue(text: ┤25├, selection: TextSelection(baseOffset: -1, extentOffset: -1, affinity: TextAffinity.downstream, isDirectional: false), composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1))

Comment: Change `value` to `text`. `weightController.text`

Comment: Your WeightData require `double` so, convert the text using `double.parse(weightController.text)`

Comment: It prints the weight I typed in but in my List there stands 'null'. My Code to show the weight looks like this: '''ListTile(
                        title: Text(weights[i].weight.toString() + ' kg'),
                        leading: Text(weights[i].date.toString()),
                      ),'''

Comment: No error it just shows 'null' instead of the value